# Is the Acceptance Rate of Users still displayed anywhere?

Tags: support, status-completed, accepted-answer, user-accounts

I cannot remember seeing the Acceptance Rate of any Users displayed recently - has that function been disabled?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has been removed in the latest build, as per [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164654/150020) discussion on meta.stackoverflow.